# String from Mysql results

Tags: php, mysql

Im grabbing voltages from a database and displaying them on the page from the code below:

```
$separator = '';

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $volt = $separator.$row['volt'];
        $separator = ',';
        echo $volt;
    }
}
```

This outputs the following:
12.34,12.45,13.01 etc how do I call this data outside the while loop?

If I echo $volt outside I get only one value ,12.34 for example not the full string?

Comment: you can concatenate the $volt to another variable to collect as you go and then display that variable outside the while loop.  Or you can just use group_concat in mysql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save your data with an array :

```
$volts = [];

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $volts[] = $row['volt'];
    }
}

echo implode(',',$volts);
```

I used [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to join all elements of the array

Comment: nice, there's always someone giving a better answer than me :D

Answer (score 0):

You can start with $volts intially set to empty string then concatenate $volt to $volts as you go then so after the while loop you have $volts containing all $volts that were available in the while loop. like this.

```
$separator = '';
$volts = '';
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $volt = $separator.$row['volt'];
        $separator = ',';
        echo $volt;
        $volts .= $volt;
    }
}
echo $volts;
```